# How do you globally remove the 'Post Reply' button from public folders in Outlook

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook, group-policy

We run on a Microsoft Small Business Server 2008 domain.  Is there a way to manipulate toolbars via Group Policy?

This is a fork from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/62085/how-do-you-configure-a-mail-enabled-exchange-2007-public-folder-so-the-reply-butt/).

Answer (score 1):

You can typically modify (remove) toolbars and menu items if you know the command ID for the toolbar or menu item. You can then disable them via Group Policy if you have the Office Group Policy templates installed. You'll need to google for the command ID's for your version of Office to find out what they are.

The other way to do it would be to create a custom form for that folder, but I haven't done that in a long time so can't help out there.

Comment: found this handy looking utility:

http://www.add-in-express.com/products/commandbars-controls-ids.php